# ThreeJS convert location on HTML to 3D space

Tags: javascript, html, web, 3d

I would like to do the opposite of [this tutorial](https://threejs.org/manual/#en/align-html-elements-to-3d) which aligns HTML elements to ones in 3D space by projecting the 3D coordinates back onto the screen.

I am able to use `unproject` and some vector math to get pretty good results with location on the screen provided I'm using locations *within* the camera frustum. This no longer works when I want to use the position of HTML elements off-screen (i.e. places on the page where the user would need to scroll to) due to the perspective camera distortion.

How can I fix this?

Given a 2D coordinate (in particular, given an HTML `element.offsetTop`) and a perspective camera, how do I convert it into 3D space?

Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't you need a distance from the camera too? A 3D point projected from a 2D coordinate can be anywhere on the ray going from the camera through the point.

Comment: Yes, I just left out the implementation details. I can get this to work fine for location within the screen space, but where it fails is when I try to compute a location off-screen like somewhere further down a webpage.